# Figure caption appears on the side instead below

Tags: captions, minipage

I am using beamer class to make a presentaation. I am using minipage to get 4 figures in 2 by 2 arrangement.

When I give captions to the figures 2 problems arise:

- The caption starts right from the figure instead of below
- Instead of decreasing the size of the figure the caption will be cut by the figure.
- I also get error: "\caption outside figure or table. \end{frame}"

> ```
> \documentclass{beamer}
> \usetheme{default}
> \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
> \begin{document}
>   \begin{frame}
>       \begin{columns}
>           \column{0.5\textwidth}
>           \begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
>               \centering
>               \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{ETRM1042-epspdf-to}
>               \caption{WT terminal voltage}
>           \end{minipage}
>           \begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
>               \centering
>               \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{ITRM1042-epspdf-to}
>               \caption{WT terminal current}
>           \end{minipage}
>           \column{0.5\textwidth}
>           \begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
>                       \centering
>                       \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{ETRM1042-epspdf-to}
>                   \caption{Caption 3}
>                   \end{minipage}
>           \begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
>               \centering
>               \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{VAACC-epspdf-to}
>               \caption{previous Vterm angle}
>           \end{minipage}
>       \end{columns}
>     \end{frame}
>    \end{document}
> ```

[image]

Comment: is it intended that there are only three captions? it is very hard to see what is happening unless you make it a complete document so people can run it, you can use `{example-image}` as the image (it is in most tex distributions)

Comment: note you have over-constrained the boxes, you have specified their height but also put in images scaled to full width and a caption. If that text does not fit into the box then tex has to over-print the surrounding text. It's rather rare to use that height option on minipage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle

There are 4 captions. Would alternative can I use instead of height ?

Comment: there are only three `\caption` in the code above.

Comment: Without a figure you should be using captionof{figure} from the caption package (or possibly already in beamer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less complication you will have with the following approach:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{WT terminal voltage}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{???}
        \\  % new row
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-b}
\caption{WT terminal current}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{previous Vterm angle}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, to see captions, your images show appropriate limit their heights.

**Edit:**
To have numbered captions, you need to add in preamble `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]`.

**Addendum:**
As asked in comment, the "captions" without word "Figure" is easy to obtain -- just not use `\caption{...}` :-). Possible solution is demonstrated in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{default}
%----
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-a}\newline\footnotesize
WT terminal voltage
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-a}\newline\footnotesize
        ???
        \\[1em]  % new row
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-b}\newline\footnotesize
WT terminal current
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=24mm]{example-image-b}\newline\footnotesize
        previous Vterm angle
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "Figure" and leave only the caption text, also it it possible to maximize more the figure sizes and reduce the white spaces in between ?

Comment: Of course, just not use `\caption{...}`. It was actulally source of your problems ... I will add to my answer example, which fulfill what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

If I run your example I get

```
! LaTeX Error: \caption outside figure or table.
```

If you get an error it isn't really worth looking at the pdf output at all, teX tries to recover to error check more of the file but not to produce sensible output.

If I add tables as the error says the output looks OK to me:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}
          \column{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{table}
              \centering
              \includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example-image}
              \caption{WT terminal voltage}
          \end{table}
          \begin{table}
              \centering
              \includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example-image-a}
              \caption{WT terminal current}
          \end{table}
          \column{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{table}
                      \centering
                      \includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example-image-b}
                  \caption{Caption 3}
                  \end{table}
          \begin{table}
              \centering
              \includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example-image}
              \caption{previous Vterm angle}
          \end{table}
      \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```